# Land Purchased from Haram money

Tags: halal-haram, business

I lived in one country for 4 years and due to some family issues i came back to my home country for good. I was advised by many friends to take loan while leaving the country. As I was not much into deen at that time, i took the wrong decision. 
I am not sure how much loan was taken on my name but I was told the loan got approved for xxxx amount and the middle men took his share and gave the rest of the amount to me. I have purchased a land using that amount.
I know this is not halal for me now, and i can not repay the loan to the bank as i don't know how much loan was actually granted on my name, also don't which bank has sanction the loan.
Could you please advice, what i can do with the land which i purchased with the loan amount.

Comment: Reach the person who took loan on your behalf and discuss the issue with him first. I am confused. How and why on earth a bank allowed you loan without reaching you first.